# How to record instagram images clicked on Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I have some instagram images showing up on my website as below

```
<a href="https://instagram.com/p/aaaaaa/" title="title of instagram image here" target="_new" id="imgLink" ><img src="https://image link here" alt=" "></a>
```

However, I can not seem to get this registered using Google Analytics, that is I want it to be recorded in Google Analytics when clicked. I am trying as below

```
    /* Tracks all a href links */
    $('a').click(function(e){
        ga('send','event','Link (Open Day)', 'Click (Open Day)',$(this).text().trim());
    })
```

Comment: No idea if that solves your problem but you should use jQuery "on"-function, because that way links will be tracked even if they dynamically inserted into your page after your click tracking script. (i.e. $("a").on( "click", function() {
  ga('send','event','Link (Open Day)', 'Click (Open Day)',$(this).text().trim());
});

Comment: No Sorry. It did not help. You are right.The images are dynamically added.

Comment: Are the images added via an iframe?

Comment: @EikePierstorff that's not true about `on` vs `click`. Supporting dynamically added content only works when using event delegation, e.g. `$(document).on('click', 'a', ...)`

Comment: @PhilipWalton, thank you ! So this might be worth testing for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to save that label as a variable before passing it in ga function.

Sometimes analytics will not pick up the event immediately since its a link. So in that case i recommend you try this code:

```
window.onload = function()
{

    var myVars = setInterval(function(){ googleads() }, 1000);
    function googleads()
    {
        $('a').click(function(e){
      ga('send','event','Link (Open Day)', 'Click (Open Day)',$(this).text().trim());
            clearInterval(myVars);
        }
    }
}
```

cool thing about it is that you can try it on the console. Hope this helps..
NOTE: ga is the universal Analytics syntax. Look out for that too

Comment: The reason why it sometimes doesn't "pick up the event" is because the browser navigates the visitor to the new page before the code has a chance to execute. So, making it wait even longer would make it even more likely to not have a chance to execute.  sidenote: if you want to just do a one-time delayed execution, you can use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and `clearInterval`

Comment: @CrayonViolent, as fair as I understand the [Ga documentation on the transport field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference) (which has replaced the sendBeacon option) Universal Analytics will now take care of cases where users navigate away and timeouts will be no longer necessary (although undoubtly they will be used for years and years to come).